# Storing Inception Model Vectors in Mysql Database using Python

Tags: python, mysql, numpy

I'm trying to store vectors extracted from an image recognition model (inception) in the smallest possible way. The original text is a numpy array of floats: `[1.63824 0.545321 2.03962 0.140029 0.15521 ...]`. So far I've tried the following:

- Storing as JSON object as TEXT field
- Storing as space delimited list as TEXT field

There are 2048 individual floating point numbers in each row. The rows are assigned an image_id => image_vector. I'm trying to compress this data because each row as json is around 44kb. As text it's about 34kb.

**Is there a better way to compress & store this data?**

Edit: Neither PostgreSQL or MyISAM are options in my situation

Comment: Store each image as a MyISAM table with 2048 rows, storing the floats as... floats (or decimals), compress the resulting tables. Optionally, combine them using the merge engine? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/merge-storage-engine.html

Comment: Hmm.. I'm currently using InnoDB. If I were to use a row for each vector point, I would end up with 2,048,000,000 rows for 1 million images.

Comment: I can understand not wanting a million separate tables, or a highly denormalized data architecture. You may bump up against the maximum number of columns, but you could try columns x1, x2, ... x2048 (with datatype float). Storing the number as text is going to take up more room than storing it as a number.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, even though I knew there was a limit on the number of columns you can have... InnoDB says there's a limit of 1017  (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html). The data would never be accessed on a column basis. It's all or none because they're vector features. I guess I wonder if there's a way to store the data in one field in some other way. Though there are actually negative floats these arrays.

Comment: MyISAM tables have the advantages of a theoretical* column maximum of 4096 columns, and table-level compression, and you format with views/functions. 
You may want to look into PostgreSQL or another open source RDBMS if MyISAM is a deal breaker. I know Postgresql has some row-level compression.
Beyond this, I think you're talking creating custom data types, which involves messing with code and recompiling, AFAIK, which probably isn't worth it.

* less with long names, AFAIK

Comment: Unfortunately neither PostgreSQL or MyISAM are options. I probably should've mentioned that in the post. I'll update it.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. At this point I'm out over my skiis, but you might check out InnoDB table compression: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-compression-usage.html

Comment: Appreciate the help though @BrianDewhirst! I'll have to look into activating compression or potentially storing the data in another way.